# Alignment of EPS figures in LaTex

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, eps

I have a question regarding the how LaTeX align EPS figures. Here I show an example of inserting two EPS figure.

I create the figures in Adobe Illustrator. The first one has a box in it, and I set the artboard size to 3.5" in AI.

The second one has a box at the same location, the artboard is set to 3.5", and I draw a 3.5" wide box the same size as the artbox.

Then I insert the two figures into the IEEEtran template which has a column width of 3.5".

In the resulting output, the two figures are not perfectly aligned. Does anyone have an idea what the reason behind this is?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\title{LaTeX Sandbox2}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1-1}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: compare the `%%BoundingBox` in the two figures. `\includegraphics` has no positioning rules at all, it just generates a box of the specified size then tex positions that as if it were a letter or tex box or any other thing of the same size.

Comment: Maybe the second image is too large for the text width and TeX reports an overfull `\hbox`. Then, either create the image with a smaller margin or scale the image down via `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1-1}`.